# Jenkins Error 128 / Git Error 403: Jenkins can't connect to my Bitbucket repository

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, bitbucket, http-status-code-403

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.04

**Hypervisor:** VirtualBox

**Network configuration:** Nat Network with port forwarding to access the vms through the host ip. I can also ping a VM from another VM.

I try to connect my Jenkins app hosted on a VM to my BitBucket server also on a VM. I followed a tutorial on internet but when i enter the address of my git repository i'm getting this:

`Failed to connect to repository : Command "usr/bin/git ls-remote -h http://admin@192.168.6.102:8005/scm/tes/repository-test.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'http://admin@192.168.6.102:8005/scm/tes/repository-test.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

So, to be sure I tried to exectute the command on the terminal... and on the terminal it seems to work.. I can also push, clone, pull etc..

[On this image you can see that it's true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A33r4.png)

Do you have an explanation?

**EDIT:**

I try some others things like use or not sudo to see if the permissions problem came from that and it seems that it's not the case.
[But I see that there is no result when we use the "HEAD" argument.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOyCg.png)

Do you think that because "HEAD" give no result, git in jenkins interprets it like no answer and returns the damn** error 403?

**EDIT 2:**

I found that on the web: http: // jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Jenkins-GIT-ls-remote-error-td4646903.html
The guy has the same problem but in a different way, I will try to allocate more RAM to see if it does the trick.

Comment: Are you using private repository in BitBucket?

Comment: No, I checked the box to make the repository "public" in the settings

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715345/jenkins-returned-status-code-128

Comment: Nope, it returns the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution.**

I had to reinstall jenkins to have a user named "jenkins" with his own home directory.

I don't know if it is linked or not, but I configured my bitbucket server to use only HTTPS with a self signed certificate (I work in lan)

My troubleshoot was linked with my proxy settings.
I disabled all my proxy settings in Linux so I was able to launch the command that did'nt worked in jenkins with terminal.

I logged with `sudo su jenkins` the commands also worked.
I found out that in the home directory of the jenkins user there was a "proxy.xml" file. I opened it and saw my old proxy settings.
I deleted all the content with vim, saved and restarted and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many possible problems, but you are getting 403 - Access Forbidden, which indicates some problem with permissions. I would suggest first common mistakes:

- a) trying https instead http - my scm only uses https,
- b) check if admin is correct - scm by default uses scmadmin.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, to use https I have to use a self signed certificate that's right? Should I also use Https for Jenkins? I think admin is correct because when I use the button "clone" in my repository it reveals: `http://admin@192.168.6.102:8005/scm/tes/repository-test.git`

Answer (score 0):

[Here I run the exact same command twice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOpBe.png)

The first time I used the proxy configuration wich I need to access internet, and the second time I set the mandatory server on "none".

So there is a problem with the damn proxy.
I was thinking that the proxy was not used in NAT connection with VirtualBox...

Answer (score -1):

there can be git version miss match.....
I would suggest you update git once. maybe it will resolve your issues.